# Math term for the distance between the center and a chord of a circle

Tags: geometry, terminology

I wonder if there is a single-word expression meaning the shortest distance between the center and a chord of a circle.

Radius is the distance from the center to the edge, so it is not the answer I'm looking for.
Especially, I want to express

[Example sentence]

```
The ___ of this dot of the circle is 3.54.
```

Comment: Don't think so. The perpendicular distance from the centre to the chord will do it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the APOTHEM

[image: APOTHEM]

In the given figure , we have the Chord of length $a$. Here , $r$ is the APOTHEM , while $R$ is the RADIUS , with the remaining $h$ being the SAGITTA.

$r+h=R$

reference :
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chord.html
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sagitta.html
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Apothem.html

Comment: Learn something every day! Use the words though and no one will know what you mean

Comment: I get what you mean , though (1) There are many uses already [ Eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry) & https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/apothem.html ] (2) The terms are more common in Certain Areas like optics & astronomy & trigonometry (3) These are Latin terms , hence they may be well known to Certain groups (4) Every common term now was uncommon in Early Stages [ Eg PI versus TAU & Neutron versus Neutrino ] # @Paul